# Show that A,B are closed but A+B is not ( for given example of A and B)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> X is a normed linear space and A,B be subsets of X. Prove that,
>
> (a) A+B is open if A is open or B is open.
>
> (b) A+B is closed if A is closed and B is compact.
>
> (c) Consider $X=c_0$, $A=\{(\alpha_n)_n \in c_0 : \alpha_m=m\alpha_{m+1} \forall m \text{ even }\}$ , $B=\{(\alpha_n)_n \in c_0 : \alpha_m=0 \forall m \text{ odd }\}$ and show that A,B are closed but A+B is not.

My attempt:

(a)Let B be open then since,$x \mapsto c+x$ is a homeomorphism, we have, $A+B = \cup_{a \in A} (a+B)$ thus being union of open sets is open.

(b)Let, $z_n=a_n+b_n$ be a sequence in $A+B$ such that it converges to some $z \in X$ . To show, $z \in A+B$ . Compactness of $B \implies \exists \{b_{n_k}\}$ converging to some $b \in B$ .
Consider, the corresponding, $z_{n_k}=a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}$, then $z_{n_k} \to z $ i.e. $a_{n_k}= z_{n_k}-b_{n_k}$ is also convergent, $A$ closed implies, $a_{n_k} \to a  \in A$ .
Thus,$a=z-b$ i.e. $z=a+b \in A+B$.

(c) I couldn't proceed on this.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Another example of closed $A,B$ in a normed linear space with $A+B$ not closed is $X=\Bbb R$ with$ \|r\|=|r|,$ with $A=\Bbb Z$ and $B= \{n+2^{-|n|}: 0\ne n\in \Bbb Z\}.$ No member of $A+B$ is an integer, but for every $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ we have $2^{-n}=(-n)+(n+2^{-n})\in A+B,$ so $0\in \overline {(A+B)}.$

Comment: In (c),  in your def'n of $A,$ the part $\alpha_m=m\alpha_{m1}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Actually I'm also confused with the notation. Can you suggest what can be a possible correction of the notation.

Comment: @Coherent Maybe it should read $\alpha_{m+1}$ instead of $\alpha_{m1}$?

Comment: @gerw. I'm waiting for confirmation from the proposer but that would likely be it.